# positioning rgb wave bar

Tags: formatting

What is the code to position the rgb wave bar on the left of page in vertical format?
Also when positioned at the bottom of page why does the line at the bottom of page shorten its length--the line should fill the width of the text?

```latex
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{printlen}
    \usepackage{layouts}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{multirow, makecell, tabularx, booktabs}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    % \usepackage{chancery}
    %preamble
    \usepackage[
      height=8.5in,      % height of the text block
      width=6.5in,       % width of the text block
      top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
      headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
      headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
      heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
      %showframe,       % show the main blocks
      verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
    ]{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
    \usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
    \usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
     \usepackage{indentfirst}
     \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, matrix, calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,positioning}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, fill=blue!20]
    \tikzstyle{eff} = [ellipse,  minimum height=2em,  draw=black, fill=pink!20]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,  ->, >=stealth]
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc}
     \usepackage{fourier-orns}

    \renewcommand\headrule{%------------fancy top line of page
    \vspace{-6pt}
    \hrulefill
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}
    {\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
    \hrulefill}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
    %-----------------------------------------
    \begin{document}
     \begin{titlepage}

    \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
        \rule[-3mm]{.5pt}{1cm}%
        \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%

        \fontfamily{stix}\selectfont
    \pagecolor{brown!20}
    \begin{center}
    \headrule\\[.25in]
     {\MakeUppercase {\huge Quality Management System Manual}}\\[2mm]
    \headrule\\[4mm]
    \textsc{\Large as per requirements of std iso 9001:2015}    \\[4mm]
                                            \begin{figure}[H]
                                            \centering
                                            \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a} 
                                            \label{DGQA Logo}
                                            \end{figure}
    \vspace*{4em}
    \textsc{\normalsize CONTROLLERATE OF QUALITY ASSURANCE\\ARMOURED VEHICLE ELECTRONICS\\GOVERNMENT OF INDIA\\ MIN OF DEFENCE (DGQA)\\AVADI, CHENNAI -- 600 054\\tel: 044-26843007, fax: 044-26841881, email:} {\normalsize  cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in}\\ 
    \vfill
    \newcount\WL \unitlength.5pt
    \begin{center}
    \begin{picture}(460,60)(355,-10)
    \sffamily \tiny \linethickness{1.25\unitlength} \WL=360
    \multiput(360,0)(1,0){456}%
    {{\color[wave]{\the\WL}\line(0,1){50}}\global\advance\WL1}
    \linethickness{0.25\unitlength}\WL=360
    \multiput(360,0)(20,0){23}%
    {\picture(0,0)
    \line(0,-1){5} \multiput(5,0)(5,0){3}{\line(0,-1){2.5}}
    \put(0,-10){\makebox(0,0){\the\WL}}\global\advance\WL20
    \endpicture}
    \end{picture}
    \end{center}
    \line(1,0){400}\\
    \scriptsize NOT TO BE COPIED OR REPRODUCED IN FULL OR PART WITHOUT PERMISSION OF CONTROLLER, CQA(AVL)
    \end{center}
    \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
        \rule[-3mm]{.5pt}{1cm}%
        \rule{3mm}{.5pt}%
    \end{titlepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{appendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Annexures}
    \end{appendix}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such things can be created with `colormaps` that ship with `pgfplots`. For instance, `/pgfplots/colormap/jet` from p. 196 of the pgfplots manual v 1.16 comes already close. I assume that if you strip down your code to the minimal necessary amount, you will get quite nice answers. The present form of the question does, however, repel users who do not really want to go through all the unrelated things.

Comment: nope--could not find anything regards positioning but an interesting read